# How to run a API GET call in node js everyday at 11:00pm

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, schedule

I have a aws API GET call in node js.

> http://localhost:3000/amazon/api

I have mentioned necessary functionalities within this call. I want to run this call everyday at 11:00PM using node js. I went through `cron and other scheduling` package documents. Bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) module to schedule tasks for specific times.

A simple example for 11am everyday might look like:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * /11 * * *', function(){
  console.log('Run your process here');
});
```